# Check whether a value is equal to the value of an attribute of some object in an array

Tags: ruby

Objects `FoodType` and `Vegetable` have an attribute `id`. There are several different `FoodType`s that are `Vegetable`s.

I want to check whether `vegetable.id` - `my_vegetable_id` -  is equal to any of the `FoodType id's that are considered a vegetable.

I have an array including several `FoodType`s:

```
valid_foodtypes = [Spinach, Cauliflower, Carrot]
```

What is the best way to check whether a given `vegetable.id` equals the `id` of any of the objects in `valid_foodtypes`?

I could do:

```
my_vegatable_id = vegatable.id
valid_foodtypes.each do |foodtype|
    if foodtype.id == vegetable.id
    # Execute code, then break because once is enough
    break
```

Is there a nicer way, perhaps a one-liner, to do this?

Comment: _"Is there a nicer, more Ruby-esque, way to do this?"_ – inheritance comes to mind when speaking of _is-a_ relationships.

Comment: For this example, true! However, in my real application it would not make sense to do inheritance here. This was just the most readable simplification I could think of.

Comment: BTW, how is this related to Rails? Any chance that your actual data is stored in a database which could handle the selection using a query?

Comment: You're right, I removed 'Rails' from the title. Not all of the actual relevant data is stored in a database for this application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do

```
if valid_foodtypes.any? {|foodtype| foodtype.id == vegetable.id }
  # code here
end
```

or:

```
if valid_foodtypes.map(&:id).include?(vegetable.id)
  # code here
end
```

Comment: Your second suggestion does not check for vegetable.id - so that doesn't do the job, right? Your first suggestion, I like very much!

Comment: It should be `valid_foodtypes.map(&:id).include?(vegetable.id)`, or use an array contain just the ids, i.e. `valid_foodtype_ids.include?(vegetable.id)`

Comment: @Stefan - I like that first solution as well!

Answer (score 0):

If `valid_foodtypes` is an array, then

```
foodtype = valid_foodtypes.find{|type| type.id == vegetable.id}
# Do whatever with the found foodtype.
# Note that foodtype can be nil!!
```

If it's a relation, then

```
foodtype = valid_foodtypes.find(vegetable.id)
```

Comment: This would then need an `if foodtype # Do stuff` to match the pseudo code. Other than that, I think it does the job.

Comment: You need an `if` somewhere anyway.